# .httaccess issue - rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this URL: `https://www.example.com/zitra/munch-edward-vykrik-(1910)-ido-6017` and I need to rewrite it into this shape: `https://www.example.com/zitra/strany/jedenobraz.php?id=6017` (my issue is to add directory "strany" into final url). I'm using this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*)-ido-(.*) jedenobraz.php?id=$2
```

I guess that's something with rewrite base, because on common.httacces testers a little bit different solution works and there is another working .htaccess file in root directory level. But I'm not able to handle it...

On example.com level is a working .httaccess, in directory zitra is .htaccess with "RewriteEngine off" and I'm testing everything in directory strany...

Many thanks for hints or tips in advance!

Comment: Where is `1702` coming from when it is not even in original URL?

Comment: That's my  mistake, the ID is always the same - there shoud be 6017 (I copied it from two urls). Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code inside **`zitra/.htaccess`**:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /zitra/

RewriteRule -(\d+)/?$ strany/jedenobraz.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanl you. I'm sorry, but it didn't help :-( with htccess you never know why :( just 404 code

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser that is causing 404? Make sure this .htaccess is located in `/zitra/` sub-directory